# Load ASP.NET Web API plugin assemblies in separate AppDomain

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, .net-assembly

I'm creating a CMS-like application under MVC.

To handle backend code for plugins I use Web API, so putting my API DLLs in /bin folder enables me to access plugin service methods by a specific route - `/api/{namespace}/{controller}/{id}`.

I would like to load the assemblies from another location, then be able to unload them in case of new module install/upgrade/delete.

People suggest to override the `DefaultAssembliesResolver` to include plugin assemblies:

```
public class PluginAssembliesResolver : DefaultAssembliesResolver
{
    public override ICollection<Assembly> GetAssemblies()
    {
        List<Assembly> assemblies = new List<Assembly>(base.GetAssemblies());

        foreach (string assemblyPath in ModuleManager.GetAllAssemblyPaths(HttpContext.Current.Server))
        {
            if (File.Exists(assemblyPath))
            {
                assemblies.Add(Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath));
            }
        }

        return assemblies;
    }
}
```

But in this case I am loading the assemblies into the current domain and I am not able to unload them.

Trying to load assemblies from another location throws an error (it recognizes my assembly, but tries to look for the same DLL under `/bin` or `/bin/myPlugin` folders):

```
AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("myDomain", null);     

Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\myPluginPath\myPlugin.dll");

domain.Load(assembly.GetName());
```

How can I load them into a separate AppDomain?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to overwrite the DefaultHttpControllerSelector.
 Here is a very nice article on the subject: [link](http://www.strathweb.com/2013/08/customizing-controller-discovery-in-asp-net-web-api/)
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try `domain.Load(assembly.FullName())` Maybe this helps. 
I'm interested in a similar application. I'm trying to find a way of loading them in different Application Domains and make it work. I'm loading my DLLs via Microsoft Addin Framework which allows me to load addins into different appDomains for the purpose of unloading them on runtime. However I'm not sure if and how ASP WebAPI can handle multpile ApplicationDomains. Application Domains restrict the communication between the two DLLs. Are you using one ASP WebApi Server or do you create

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
The `assembly.FullName` just returns the display name of the same assembly, so this is useless.
I also got familiar with some issues regarding to AppDomains during the work process. In my case the problem is that ASP.NET loads and configures Web API assemblies ONLY on application start, so I'm still not able to install a new extension and use its methods (API controllers/actions in our case) without restarting the application.
Thank you, anyways.